# Recursively copy the contents of subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, cp

I want to copy the contents of `src` folders to new directories at a different location that have the names of the original `src` directories' parent directories.

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve.

Input

```
source/folder1/src
source/folder2/src
source/folder3/src
```

Output (All folders should contain the contents of `src` folder)

```
dest/folder1
dest/folder2
dest/folder3
```

Comment: so, you don't want to keep the `src` directories as directories - you want to move their contents to their parents, and move the parents to another location?

Comment: @Zanna yes this is what I want.

Comment: Questions on macos should be posted on [unix.se] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 5):

You can use `for`

```
for d in /path/to/source/*; do echo mkdir /path/to/dest/"$(basename $d)" && echo cp -rvb -- /path/to/source/"$d"/src/* /path/to/dest/"$(basename $d)"; done
```

If you are doing this from the parent directory of `source` and `dest`, you can use relative paths:

```
for d in source/*; do echo mkdir dest/"$(basename $d)" && echo cp -rvb -- "$d"/src/* dest/"$(basename $d)"; done
```

After testing, remove `echo` to actually copy the files

```
for d in source/*; do mkdir dest/"$(basename $d)" && cp -rvb -- "$d"/src/* dest/"$(basename $d)"; done
```

More readable...

```
for d in /path/to/source/*; do 
  echo mkdir /path/to/dest/"$(basename $d)" && 
  echo cp -rvb -- /path/to/source/"$d"/src/* /path/to/dest/"$(basename $d)"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

With `tar`:

```
(cd source; tar c .) | tar x --transform 's:/src::' -C dest
```

- `cd source; tar c .` creates a tar archive of the `source` directory and sends it to the pipe
- the second `tar` reads that archive from the pipe, then
- extracts it (`x`) to the `dest` directory (`-C dest`),
- applies the `sed` command `s:/src::` on the resulting path (remove the first occurrence of `/src` in the path)

This assumes that the `source` directory's actual name (and those of `folder1`, `folder2`, etc.) does not contain `src`.

Comment: `tar: Option --transform is not supported` facing issues in mac

Comment: Sorry, mac is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add -r to copy all subfolders and files, -r will do it recursively

`cp -r source/folderX/src dest/folderX`

Comment: folderX is not fixed in my case I want to copy all folders within source recursively and that wouldn't have fixed prefix even.